# Converting .rpm to .deb using alien

Tags: ubuntu, rpm, packaging, deb, alien

I am trying to convert `.rpm` to `.deb` using alien command:

```
sudo alien <name of package>.rpm
```

But it's just create a directory that has the same name but never get `.deb` to install it

There is no errors while converting it

How could I get `.deb`?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125154/converting-rpm-to-deb-using-alien

Comment: @steeldriver that's mine as well , is that not allowed?

Comment: It's discouraged: see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 0):

`alien` should default to using the `--to-deb` argument, according to the man page, but to be safe, try specifying it explicitly. According to the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien):

```
sudo alien --to-deb /path/to/file.rpm
```

Comment: That's same what I've already tried , doesn't solve it